# How do I overload an operator to work with a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading

I have a struct called Readings and I want to overload the < operator to work with it. It's to compare two readings and determine which one is larger.

Here's my struct:

```
struct Reading {
    int hour;
    double temperature;
    Reading(int h, double t): hour(h), temperature(t) { }
};
```